# Why doesn't Integer.valueOf of a digit Character return its value?

Tags: java, sqldatatypes

I have to say that this was found by a mistake, as I was trying to convert a `String` to an `Integer`, but I didn't realize that it is a `Character` type instead of `Integer`.

But somehow, the `Integer.valueOf` can still run with a `Character` parameter although this was not mentioned in [JDK documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)?

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("2"));  // >>> 2
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf('2'));  // >>> 50
```

While it works fine for `String` argument of `"2"`, it doesn't provide the expected result for `Character` argument of `'2'`. Why does this happen?

I am trying to understand if I miss anything? Why does it return 50 instead of 2?

Thanks

---

OK, I checked the ASCII table, it is returning 50 because the index for `Character` `'2'` is 50.

Comment: A char is an unsigned 16 bit integer type. '2' is simply another way of specifying the integer 50. '2'==50 will return true. '2' is simply promoted to an int for [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-)

Comment: A `char` is a numeric type, despite the fact that it doesn't look like a numeric type.

Answer (score 5):

The ASCII representation should give you a clue about why you are getting this behaviour.

Remember that the Integer and Character classes are wrappers for the int and char primitive types. The reason why `Integer.valueOf()` works with a Character is that there is an implicit cast to Integer. When you cast a Character to Integer, the Integer will hold the ASCII code for that Character. The same thing happens with primitive types. For example

```
 Character yourChar = new Character('2');
 Integer yourInt = Integer.valueOf(yourChar);    //Implicit casting

 char biz = '2';
 int baz = (int)biz;                            //Explicit casting to int

 System.out.println(baz);
 System.out.println(yourInt);
```

Here, the value of both yourInt and baz will be 50, because that is the ASCII code for '2'. The implicit and explicit casting do the same thing.

If you actually want to convert a char which holds a digit to the correct integer, use Character.getNumericValue(). E.g.

```
 char myChar = '2';
 int myInt = Character.getNumericValue(myChar);
```

Now myInt holds the value 2.

As far as best-practices go, using this type of implicit conversion isn't a good idea. It doesn't make it obvious what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Integer.valueOf(char)) gives the ASCII value.

```
Integer.valueOf('2');  // >>> 50
```

If you want to get numeric value then,

```
Character.getNumericValue('2'));  // >>> 2
```

Comment: You are right, but I am asking why does java allow `Integer.valueOf(Character)`? This was not written in JDK documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: Well, Number 2 is passed as a Character not as a int. So that  Integer.valueOf return the ASCII value of character '2'.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, char or Character really matter here ?

Comment: @Rowi: I'm not sure, maybe not with auto-unboxing.

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 *You are right, but I am asking why does java allow Integer.valueOf(Character)* It's calling [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) because of [*widening primitive conversion*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) (JLS-5.1.2 link) (`char` is widened to `int`). As for why that is allowed, `'a' + 1 == 'b'` (which I hope helps).